# Nuxt middleware not seeing updated store on SSR

Tags: plugins, server-side-rendering, nuxt.js

Authentication works fine, except on first page load i.e. SSR. When I check my console.log I see that the console.log from my middleware is always executed at SSR level, eventhough I added ssr:false in my config.

What I did was this:

In nuxt.config.ts I added

```
{
    src: '~/plugins/authenticated.js',
    mode: 'client'
}
```

This code is executed successfully, I can see this by checking my developers console's "vue plugin".

In my "component / page" I added a middleware:

```
export default {
    middleware: [
        'authenticated'
    ]
}
```

When I run the following code in my middleware, it always shows "false" eventhough in the store the value is set to true.

```
console.log(store.state.users.logged);
```

It's driving me nuts, can someone tell me how to get middleware working on first page load? we must have SSR because we need SEO et cetera, but we also do need middleware to work.

Using the latest Nuxt en VueX versions (same for Axios).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it with a mixin. Mixin with the mounted method is only runs on the client side. I hope I have helped you

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, I will give that a try ;)